# Finding a bound on a sequence defined as ratios of the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $(a_n)$ defined such that $a_n = F_n/F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. I want to show that there exists a real $b \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq b |a_{n+1} - a_n|$$
holds for all $n \geq 1$. I've been able to rearrange this inequality to:
$$\frac{1}{|(1+a_n)(1+a_{n+1})|}\leq b$$
but here I get stuck. I recognize that the terms in $(a_n)$ are not uniformly increasing or decreasing, i.e. the subsequence $(a_{2n})$ is increasing and the subsequence $(a_{2n+1})$ is decreasing, but I don't know if this is useful. Any help?

Comment: Very similar [How to prove that $|w_{n+1}-w_n| \leq (2/3)^2 |w_n - w_{n-1}|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212192) (actually it is the same, the sequence is just shifted Fibonacci sequence)